# Determining the most frequent casing of a word in Python

Tags: python

I have a text and a I want to determine the most frequent casing of each word and create a dictionary with it. This is an extract of the text:

```
PENCIL: A pencil is an object we use to write. Pencil should not be confused by pen, which is a different object. A pencil is usually made from a pigment core inside a protective casing.
```

For example, a word like "pencil" could appear as "Pencil", "PENCIL" or "pencil" in my text. I would like to create a function that would first determine which of those options is the most frequent one. I have started by classifying all the words into three groups, depending on casing, though I don't know how to determine which case is the most frequent one (I guess I'd have to do a comparison across the three lists, but I don't know how to do that):

```
list_upper = []
list_lower = []
list_both = []

for word in text:
    if isupper(word):
        list_upper.append(word)
    if islower(word):
        list_lower.append(word)
    if word == word.title():
        list_both.append(word)
```

Then, it will create a dictionary in which the first key would be the lowercase words and the values would be the most frequent type. For example: `pencil, Pencil`. I'm not sure how to do this either... This is my desired output:

```
my_dictionary = {"pencil":"Pencil", "the":"THE"...}
```

Comment: For your third case you could check `word == word.title()`

Comment: Is `text `already an iterable of words? What about `'pEnCiL'`?

Comment: @timgeb Text is iterable and casing can only have three options. Words like `pEnCiL` don't appear in my text.

Comment: Could you provide an input sample?

Comment: Should casing. and casing be considered as the same word?

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `text` is already an iterable of words and that words like `'pEnCiL'` cannot occur.

Instead of building these three lists, you can start constructing a dictionary with the counts right away. I suggest using a `defaultdict` which returns `Counter` instances when a key is missing.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

cases = defaultdict(Counter)
for word in text:
    cases[word.lower()][word] += 1
```

For a list `text` with the content

```
['pencil', 'pencil', 'PENCIL', 'Pencil', 'Pencil', 'PENCIL', 'rubber', 'PENCIL']
```

this will produce the following `cases` dictionary.

```
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'pencil': Counter({'PENCIL': 3, 'Pencil': 2, 'pencil': 2}),
             'rubber': Counter({'rubber': 1})})
```

From here, you can construct the final result as follows.

```
result = {w:c.most_common(1)[0][0] for w, c in cases.items()}
```

This will give you

```
{'pencil': 'PENCIL', 'rubber': 'rubber'}
```

in this example. If two cases appear equally often, an arbitrary one is picked as the most common.

**~edit~**

Turns out `text` is *not* an iterable of words. [Daniel Mesejo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53103005/3620003) has a regular expression which can help you extract the words from a string.

Comment: FYI OP updated the question with a sample text which added complexity to the parsing of `word in text`.

Comment: @Idlehands sigh... after confirming my question whether `text` was already an iterable of words.

Comment: To be exact, OP only confirmed Text is iterable, not *of words* :) though I know that feel.

Comment: @timgeb your code works because I tokenized my text before running the code! however, instead of choosing a random word when two words are tied, what could I do to choose the one that appeared first?

Comment: \*Complexity intensifies* :D

Comment: @MeAll In case of CPython 3.6 or any Python 3.7+ version, you will get the first word.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Counter with defaultdict:

```
import re
from collections import Counter, defaultdict


def words(t):
    return re.findall('\w+', t)


text = """PENCIL: A pencil is an object we use to write.
Pencil should not be confused by pen, which is a different object.
A pencil is usually made from a pigment core inside a protective casing.
Another casing with different Casing"""

table = defaultdict(list)
for word in words(text):
    table[word.lower()].append(word)

result = {key: Counter(values).most_common(1)[0][0] for key, values in table.items()}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'casing': 'casing', 'be': 'be', 'core': 'core', 'another': 'Another', 'object': 'object', 'should': 'should', 'from': 'from', 'write': 'write', 'pen': 'pen', 'protective': 'protective', 'a': 'a', 'which': 'which', 'pencil': 'pencil', 'different': 'different', 'not': 'not', 'is': 'is', 'by': 'by', 'inside': 'inside', 'to': 'to', 'confused': 'confused', 'with': 'with', 'pigment': 'pigment', 'we': 'we', 'use': 'use', 'an': 'an', 'made': 'made', 'usually': 'usually'}
```

First create a dictionary where the keys are the lower case variant of each word and the values are a list of the corresponding occurrences. Then use Counter to count the number of each casing and get the most common. Note the use of regex to extract the words.

Answer (score 1):

You have two great answers already.  Just for fun I figured we could try just using the builtins since you have already tokenized the words:

```
# Create a temp dict within the main dict that counts the occurrences of cases
d= {}
for word in words:
    d.setdefault(word.lower(), {}).setdefault(word, 0)
    d[word.lower()][word] += 1

# Create a function to convert the temp d back to its most common occurrence
def func(dct):
    return sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1])[-1][0]

# Use function and dictionary comprehension to convert the results.
result = {k: func(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Test case:

```
text = """
PENCIL: A pencil is an object we use to write. 
Pencil should not be confused by pen, which is a different object.
A pencil is usually made from a pigment core inside a protective casing.
PENCIL PENCIL PENCIL Pigment Pigment Pigment Pigment
""" 
# Added last line to produce a different result

result
# {'pencil': 'PENCIL', 
#  'a': 'a', 'is': 'is', 
#  'an': 'an', 'object': 'object', 
#  'we': 'we', 'use': 'use', 'to': 'to', 
#  'write': 'write', 'should': 'should', 
#  'not': 'not', 'be': 'be', 'confused': 
#  'confused', 'by': 'by', 'pen': 'pen', 
#  'which': 'which', 'different': 'different', 
#  'usually': 'usually', 'made': 'made', 
#  'from': 'from', 'pigment': 'Pigment', 
#  'core': 'core', 'inside': 'inside', 
#  'protective': 'protective', 'casing': 'casing'}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! As I mentioned before, if two words are tied, would this return the one that appeared first or would this return a random word?

Comment: If in case of ties, what are the order of returns for the three cases? Currently it should return in orders of `lower()`, `title()`, `upper()` in case of ties (first to last, tested in Python 3.7)